# Clustering or other mechanisms for implementing generic spam detection

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

In normal case I had tried out naive bayes and linear SVM earlier to classify data related to certain specific type of comments related to some page where I had access to training data manually labelled and classified as spam or ham.

Now I am being told to check if there are any ways to classify comments as spam where we don't have a training data. Something like getting two clusters for data which will be marked as spam or ham given any data.

I need to know certain ways to approach this problem and what would be a good way to implement this.

I am still learning and experimenting . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: While surprisingly simply using KMeans and using some similar features from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/ (spam-base dataset) and some additional like repeated string score, num symbols , having links score and 12-13 more features ,What I get from that after fetching 3 central clusters out of 5 is 2 of them are almost 90 percent completely spam and one is not. Semi Supervised learning is what worked finally.

Comment: Sometimes trying out is a better solution. There can always be an unconventional way to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could get to was this [research work](http://ceas.cc/2009/papers/ceas2009-paper-30.pdf) which mentions about active learning. So what I came up with is that I first performed Kmeans clustering and got the central clusters (assuming 5 clusters I took 3 clusters descending ordered by length) and took 1000 msgs from each. Then I would assign it to be labelled by the user. The next process would be training using logistic regression on the labelled data and getting the probabilities of unlabelled data and then if I have probability close to 0.5 or in range of 0.4 to 0.6 which means it is uncertain I would assign it to be labelled and then the process would continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *spam* and *ham* then it is *classification*, and you will have to provide training data.

Clustering is more likely to produce clusters such as "spanish email" vs "english email".

Without *supervision*, how would the computer know you are looking for "spam" and not "messages written on monday"? That latter is probably a much better cluster.

#### Clustering is not a substitute for classification

It solves a fundamentally different task.

Comment: The problem was with labelling 100 thousand posts all the time. I get your point. So semi supervised learning would lead to less effort and I used it.